# Move Cart to Header in Magento 1.7

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, cart, header

I’m having trouble in moving the mini cart from sidebar to header. I’ve tried all the tutorials available in the internet but it doesn’t work.

I also tried adding this in the header block of layout\page.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"
```

And then in my page\html\header.phtml, I use the code below to call the cart but nothing happened.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcart'); ?>
```

The solution above works in magento 1.6, but not in version 1.7

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2):

In Local.xml add this :

```
<reference name="header">
            <!-- add cart to header -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="header-cart" template="checkout/cart/header-cart.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

In header.phtml add this :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header-cart'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see post:

[Move Cart to Header In Magento 1.8.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40430/move-cart-to-header-in-magento-1-8-1/40436?noredirect=1#comment55546_40436)

" (1) In yourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml:

> ```
> //Place following code where you want Cart to show:
> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?>
> ```

"
"Please copy and paste base/default/layout/checkout.xml into YOURTHEME/layout. Then rename

> ```
> <reference name="right"> 
>  with 
> <reference name="header">"
> ```

"Normaly the cart is not in right column anymore. Also the cart should appear in the header if you still have getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?> in header.phtml"