# Move Cart to Header In Magento 1.8.1

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, header

**TOPIC:**
Looking to move Shopping Cart to Header-Right in Magento 1.8.1

**ATTEMPTS + OTHER POSTS:**

[How to add a Cart Icon to header?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31109/how-to-add-a-cart-icon-to-header/31145#31145)

[Move Cart to Header in Magento 1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15610/move-cart-to-header-in-magento-1-7)

Any contribution is greatly appreciated.

**Shopping Cart Icon & # Of Products In Cart - DISPLAYED AT RIGHT-HEADER is the end goal.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. in yourTheme/layout/local.xml

```
<layout>
<default>    
<!-- Unset cart from sidebar -->    
    <reference name="right"><action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action></reference>
    <!-- Insert cart in header -->
    <reference name="header"><action method="insert"><blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName></action></reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

> 2. in yourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml:

```
// This is required to show the cart
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?>
```

Normaly the cart should appear in the header.

Edit **`yourTheme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml`** to give the look you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the post. I did not find local.xml in the Layout folder. I found a local.xml in /app/etc folder? Should I create a new local.xml in the /Layout folder or edit the one in /etc folder?

Comment: Create app/design/frontend/yourPackage(default?)/yourTheme/layout/local.xml. Then do every layout modifications in local.xml. This way you'll keep your customizations in case of Magento Update

Comment: I updated my answer concerning the local.xml file. Please try again

Comment: I changed the code to the updated one, no change :/, and flushed cache etc.

Comment: Please give me the exact path of your local.xml. Also did you well configurated your Magento Theme in System > Configuration > Design Tab > Package & Theme ? Maybe this link can help : http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Comment: Hi, the path is /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/layout local.xml | Yes, for the Design tab Packages is DEFAULT | and Themes section is Pagayo-theme-001 for all fields|

Comment: ok local.xml and magento configuration looks good. Please confirm that the path of your header.phtml is app/design/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/template/page/html/header.phtml and that it contain <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?>

Comment: Anyway just with the local.xml the cart should be removed from right column. Is it the case ?

Comment: Hi, yes under <div class="header-right"> , I put the cart_sidebar code ||| No, the local.xml did not remove the cart from right column! Thanks!

Comment: I went to inspect element on the Cart container - it said <div class="block block-cart"> , does this have anything to do with the name of cart?

Comment: Since cart isn't removed from right column we have a problem with local.xml. Please check your local.xml with http://validator.w3.org/. If there is no errors then maybe cart_sidebar is not the good block name. So check if there is checkout.xml in pagayo-theme-001/layout, if not check in default/layout, if not check in base/default/template/layout/checkout.xml. In the first checkout.xml that you find search the string <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" and once you have find it look at the name attribute. Is it cart_sidebar ?

Comment: Hi, I have checked the Validator.w3.org - It said Passed with 2 warnings (Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.) (Warning No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.) ||| I found Checkout.xml in base/default/layout The line is <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-"> , I believe it is the same name attribute?

Comment: Yes it is the same name attribute. For an obscure reason it looks like local.xml is ignored by Magento and i don't know why. So please copy and paste base/default/layout/checkout.xml in pagayo-theme-001/layout. Then rename <reference name="right"> with <reference name="header">. Normaly the cart is not in right column anymore. Also the cart should appear in the header if you still have <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?> in header.phtml.

Comment: Yes! its there now! Could you please tell me how or where to edit the positioning/css of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, not the best solution but well ... The positioning depend of where you insert <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?> in header.phtml. Then about CSS, copy and paste skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css in skin/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/css and add your css here.

Comment: In fact copy and past images folder too. Normaly we should create pagayo.css file but i think we've done enough for today ;)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't move the styles.css from default to pagayo folder because I found the "block-cart" attributes in Pagayo style.css file | Please see http://www.statis-online.com - how the cart is positioned? How can I make it aligned with logo / others horizontally?? Thanks a LOTTTT

Comment: Is it safe to copy all those folders over o_o? Wouldn't that change how the pagayo theme layout looks??

Comment: If pagayo theme already have style.css and images folder then no need to copy and past from default theme

Comment: In order to align header cart block, one solution is to change width: 220px with width: auto; to fololowing class : .header-usps .usp1, .header-usps .usp2, .header-usps .usp3. PS : don't hesitate to vote up my answer even if you already validated it

Comment: Hey, yeah I tried to upvote it, but I need 15+ reputation, will do as soon as I have it!

Comment: Got 15+ Rep now, upvoted. Thanks again ^^

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40869/how-to-change-cart-to-only-show-of-products-price?noredirect=1#comment55919_40869 New question regarding cart! Plz help if you know

Comment: Hi, thanks for previous help: Please see new goal! http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51584/how-to-create-interactive-shopping-cart-icon-in-right-header/51586?noredirect=1#comment69749_51586

Answer (score 1):

In Local.xml add this :

```
<reference name="header">
            <!-- add cart to header -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="header-cart" template="checkout/cart/header-cart.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

In header.phtml add this :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header-cart'); ?>
```