# How to change Cart to only show #of Products & Price?

Tags: cart, ce-1.8.1.0, header

http://www.statis-online.com

**The cart in Header is cart_sidebar.**
It has been moved to Header-Right.

I would like to **RESIZE & CUSTOMIZE** this to **only show Price / Qty of products**. 
Right now, if a product is added to cart, it will show recently added products as well.

**What is the simplest way?** Or if I need to change from cart_sidebar to something else, please provide instructions.

All contributions are appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question with code from the cart phtml file. This is a custom theme so we need the source code to help you

Comment: Hi thank you, I have updated the question with cart.phtml code

Comment: And there isn't another file for the sidecart? Please use the template hints to check. I think your custom theme should have a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well the question is : How to remove recently added products from cart sidebar ?
If I am right, open yourtheme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml.
If this file doesn't exist then copy base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml and past it to yourtheme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml.

Remove the following code :

```
<p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>
        <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
```

In case you didn't copy sidebar.phtml from base/default theme and past in yourtheme/template/checkout/cart/ then maybe it will not be exactly the same piece of code but for sure you'll find

```
<ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
```

Remove it and the title just before

Comment: Awesome!! It worked!! Where can I customize positioning and text of "My Cart" and 1 Item in your cart, etc. And positioning of the checkout button?

Comment: Hi- if you are still reading this, since you've helped me move CART from SIDEBAR to HEADER - I am looking to customize it a bit - Please help:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51584/how-to-create-interactive-shopping-cart-icon-in-right-header/51586?noredirect=1#comment69749_51586

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [Magento - How to get cart items total in header.phtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925271/magento-how-to-get-cart-items-total-in-header-phtml)

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()
```

To figure out which template to edit try turn on magento template path hint

Comment: OP wants to know how to remove several elements and show price ant qty per item