# How to create Mouseover Shopping Cart Icon in right header?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart

**GOAL:** Add a SHOPPING CART ICON to Magento 1.8.1 - Ideal Cart will look like this: http://www.cctvhotdeals.com/ And contain the features such as # of items, mouseover to show items, etc.

**To Clarify the goal:Currently my Sidebar.phtml code is:**

> ```
> <?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
> <div class="block block-cart">
> <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
> <div class="block-title">
> <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
> </div>
> <div class="block-content">
> <?php if ($_cartQty>0): ?>
>    <div class="summary">
>
>        <?php if ($_cartQty==1): ?>
>            <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There is <a href="%s">1 item</a> >in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?></p>
>        <?php else: ?>
>            <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There are <a href="%s">%s >items</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?></p>
>        <?php endif ?>
> ```

I want the **subtotal**, **order details**, and **checkout buttons** to show in another block when **MOUSEOVER** the shopping cart: Current code showing in the cart block:

> ```
>        <p class="subtotal">
>            <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
>                <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER >TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
>            <?php else: ?>
>                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?></span> ><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
>                <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
>                    <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
>                <?php endif; ?>
>            <?php endif; ?>
>       </p>
>    </div>
>   <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
>     <?php endif ?>
>     <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
>     <div class="actions">
>    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
>    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" >onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo >$this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
>    </div>
>    <?php endif ?>
>   <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
>    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
>
>       <?php else: ?>
>           <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping >cart.') ?></p>
> ```

**I've found another post regarding this but cannot understand Jquery or what they are talking about:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344838/jquery-hover-and-stay-until-mouse-out

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** Create local.xml at

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourTemplate/layout/
```

add this code at this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_header" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This code is call cart side bar to header section.

**Step2:** on header.phtml call this cart sidebar using below code :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar_header');?>
```

then rest of you need to put your logic

**[Update]** I have update code for sidebar

```
<?php 
$count=0;
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
    $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    if ($count >= 1) { $text = $this->__('Cart (%s)', $count); } 
    elseif ($count > 0) {$text = $this->__('Cart (%s)', $count); }
    else { $text = $this->__('Cart (0)'); }

}?>
<div class="i_cart" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()" onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">
    <p class="item">MY CART</p>
    <p class="cart_digit">
        <?php echo $count; ?>
    </p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('headsidebar').style.display="block";
}

function hide_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('headsidebar').style.display="noone";
}
</script>

<?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
<div class="block block-cart" id="headsidebar">
    <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <?php if ($_cartQty>0): ?>
        <div class="summary">
            <?php if ($_cartQty==1): ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There is <a href="%s">1 item</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There are <a href="%s">%s items</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <p class="subtotal">
                <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
                    <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
                    <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                        <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
    <div class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>
        <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I used to have the sidebar cart at the header - but it doesn't show the "Icon" for a shopping cart can you please explain how I can make it look and function like: http://www.cctvhotdeals.com/ (but different color for my website) ? Thank you for the help

Comment: The Sidebar.phtml code you provided made the website turn into blank page, how do I add a shopping cart icon and link it to the cart is my question?

Comment: just remove it...

Comment: ya i did, still want to know how to make cart with icon in header, I successfully moved the sidebar cart to header through the help previous posts: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40869/how-to-change-cart-to-only-show-of-products-price?noredirect=1#comment55998_40869 , AND http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40430/move-cart-to-header-in-magento-1-8-1

Comment: Please ckd.. code is update

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, that code did not function as a mouseover at all - I found another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344838/jquery-hover-and-stay-until-mouse-out regarding this but do not understand how to use Jquery, could you tell me what file I need to edit?

Comment: Hi Amit, everything is fixed with the cart, it is currently in the header right section. Do you know how to implement JQUERY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344838/jquery-hover-and-stay-until-mouse-out | Where can I place the code from that post?